# Crash when resetting value in Swift dictionary

Tags: swift

I've been working with the Swift programming language in Xcode and I believe I have run across a bug, only I'm not completely sure. When I compile and run the following program:

> ```
> import Foundation
>
> typealias GeneratorCallback = () -> AnyObject?
> typealias NamedGenerators = [String: GeneratorCallback]
>
> var generators = NamedGenerators()
>
> class ValueResetter {
>   let name: String
>   let originalValue: AnyObject?
>
>   init(name: String, value: AnyObject?) {
>       self.name = name
>       originalValue = generators[self.name]?()
>       println("The original value is \(originalValue)")
>       generators[self.name] = { value }
>   }
>
>   deinit {
>       println("Resetting \(self.name) to \(self.originalValue)")
>       generators[self.name] = { self.originalValue }
>   }
> }
>
> func applyAndResetValue(name: String, value: AnyObject?) {
>   let resetter = ValueResetter(name: name, value: value)
>   println("The value is \(generators[name]?())")
> }
>
> let valueName = "Value"
> applyAndResetValue(valueName, 1)
> println("The value is \(generators[valueName]?())")
>
> applyAndResetValue(valueName, 2)
> println("The value is \(generators[valueName]?())")
> ```

It will output:

```
The original value is nil
The value is Optional(1)
Resetting Value to nil
The value is nil
The original value is nil
The value is Optional(2)
Resetting Value to nil
```

And then crash on the second call to deinit with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
What do people know about this cause of this crash?

Comment: I got the following: `The original value is nil
The value is Optional(1)
Resetting Value to nil
0  swift                    0x0000000102dd0a68 swift(17510,0x7fff77f06300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fdc21e77588: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
`

Answer (score 2):

There should probably be a compile error here, but there isn't. You are strongly capturing an object while in the object's deinit. In other words:

```
deinit {
    println("Resetting \(self.name) to \(self.originalValue)")
    generators[self.name] = { self.originalValue }
}
```

captures `self` which is currently being de-initialized.

Changing the deinit to this fixes the crash:

```
deinit {
    let value: AnyObject? = self.originalValue
    println("Resetting \(self.name) to \(value)")
    generators[self.name] = { value }
}
```